# How to troubleshoot in vitro formaldehyde fixation for nucleosomes?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, physiology, cancer

For an experiment, I am trying to fix the mononucleosomes (100ng) using formaldehyde as crosslinking agent in HEPES buffer. I have been using 2% formaldehyde in a reaction buffer containing 1mM EDTA, 25mM NaCl and 50mM HEPES, pH 7.5 (same as nucleosomes suspension buffer) to fix mononucleosomes.

In my first reaction, I added 100ng of nucleosomes, 2% formaldehyde and incubated at 4degC, 30', then I added 0.4% SDS and incubated for 30' at RT. I observed less intense but equally sharp band for nucleosomes (less smear) as compared to unfixed nucleosomes.

When I performed the same reaction again, the gel showed a huge smear covering the entire lane instead of a sharp band.

I have been reading about the fixation reactions and encountered an emphasis on using methanol free formaldehyde (while I was using 10-15% methanol containing formaldehyde). Do you think that can be one factor for not being able to get similar results?

Comment: Same reaction protocol giving undersirable result may simply be because of some sample prep errors. See [this](http://cshprotocols.cshlp.org/content/2018/4/pdb.prot082594.full) protocol. The final concentration of formaldehyde is 1%. Most protocols suggest that formaldehyde be prepared fresh. This is because formaldehyde gets oxidized to formic acid.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The chance of adding errors while making the reaction is relatively constant since I prepare it in the same manner, every time (except for the pipetting errors). I agree with you about the oxidation of formaldehyde. The protocol you suggested uses 11% of final formaldehyde, is it because they are using certain mammalian cell lines?

Comment: Their fixation buffer contains 11% formaldehyde. They add 20ml of this buffer to 200ml of cell suspension. So final concentration of formaldehyde is 1%.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Thanks though.

Comment: Since formaldehyde is the matter of discussion here, I wanted to ask that I have an 1ml aliquot of pure formaldehyde sealed with inert gas in a glass. Now, in one reaction I am only using 10ul from that 1ml. Ideally since these aliquots are for  one time use, I shoud discard remaining 990ul but if I want to store, is there a feasible way to preserve the rest of the formaldehyde while taking care of its exposure to air?

Comment: That is a different question and should be asked in [chemistry.se]. That said, I think that most people who do these experiments prepare "fresh formaldehyde" by heating paraformaldehyde solution. You should look at the protocols for more details.